# What would be a better approach a temp table or ordinary table?

Tags: sybase, temp-tables

I have a stored procedure where I need to hold some data and process it.I am using a temp table (#temp) for this purpose. Now as temp table is stored in tempDb and this will cause an inter database communication so would it be better to create a normal table? Is there any other benefits of #temp table?

Comment: What did you mean **Inter database communication**? Can you please explain in details! What type of communication or what? Otherwise #Temp is best way to store temporary data.

Comment: As Temp tables are always created in tempDb database of the database server,whenever we access this table (select/update) it hit the tempDb database from the current working database.This is what I meant by Inter database communication

Comment: Ya it is but, It effects you when you **change your SQL Connection**. I mean, each time when your connection exist your temp tables automatically get dropped you will not get that table if and only if your connection change. So, you will not have any problem till you have the single SQL Connection. So, Which platform in you are?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While communication with a temp table is technically an 'interdatabase' communication, tempdb is usually highly cached (or can be configured as such), so it's more likely to be a read from memory, then it is a read from disk.

By default, temp tables are also only accessible by the process that created it, which protects the data from being read by unauthorized users.  Cleanup of the tables is managed automatically as well.  It can also help reduce contention for resources in the working database.

From a practical standpoint, a regular database can be finely tuned to offer better performance than a #temp table, but for most purposes, a #temp table is going to be a more practical solution.

Tempdb overview:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc31654.1550/html/sag1/X73131.htm

Tempdb Performance and Tuning:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00841.1502/html/phys_tune/X94507.htm